# accessing definitions from sub class in templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I have trouble to build a class which itself contains a subclass which self derives from class which needs template parameters from the top class. Sound horrible and it is indeed deep inside some MTP construction. But have a look on a simple example which I could shrink from the real code.

I leave the names as is in my original source. They are not important here.

```
template <typename ... T>
class ConstructAll: public T...
{
    public:
        using ConstructorParms = int;
        using BASES_T = ConstructAll<T...>;
        ConstructAll(int){}
};

template <typename T>
class WithTemplate
{
};

class WithoutTemplate
{
};


template <typename X>
class CircuitFromNetlist
{
    private:
        class SerialReader: public ConstructAll<
                            WithTemplate<X>    // use this-> don't compile
                            //WithoutTemplate  // but this works
                            >
    {
        public:
            SerialReader( typename BASES_T::ConstructorParms p): BASES_T( p ) {}
    };

    public:
        CircuitFromNetlist()
        {
            SerialReader ser{1};
        }
};

int main()
{
    CircuitFromNetlist<int> c;
}
```

If I use `WithTemplate<X>`it did not compile and runs into:

main.cpp:31:40: error: 'BASES_T' has not been declared
                 SerialReader( typename BASES_T::ConstructorParms p): BASES_T( p ) {}
                                        ^~~~~~~
main.cpp: In constructor 'CircuitFromNetlist::SerialReader::SerialReader(int)':
main.cpp:31:70: error: class 'CircuitFromNetlist::SerialReader' does not have any field named 'BASES_T'
                 SerialReader( typename BASES_T::ConstructorParms p): BASES_T( p ) {}

If I flip the code to use non templated class it seems to work.

Some idea to get the thing working?

Comment: G++ and Clang both choke on this... odd. `using BASES_T = typename ConstructAll<WithTemplate<X>>::BASES_T;` does fix the error but it shouldn't be necessary in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is causing this to fail to compile with your current compiler but this appears to compile and build fine on MSVS2017 CE.

Comment: And in addition I can't write your using statement, because I use SerialReader also as template parameter in the classes which I give as template parameter... I will look if I can copy the complete parameter list ( which is very long, because it defines the serializable types... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing here is actually correct behavior according to the C++11 standard:

> In the deﬁnition of a class or class template, **if a base class depends on a template-parameter, the base class scope is not examined during unqualiﬁed name lookup** either at the point of deﬁnition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member. -- [temp.dep] (emphasis mine)

When you inherit from `ConstructAll<WithoutTemplate>`, the base class does not depend on the template parameter `X`, but obviously inheriting from `ConstructAll<WithTemplate<X>>` the base class does depend on this template parameter.

You will have to explicitly refer to the type as `typename ConstructAll<WithTemplate<X>>::BASES_T`.